# Visual Studio 2008 sp1 classic asp Intellisense and Outlining not functioning

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, asp-classic, intellisense

As the topic suggests I've got VS 2008 with sp1 installed and am not receiving full Intellisense or ANY outlining capabilities when editing classic asp pages. My coworker is also using VS2008sp1 and has outlining working correctly (but he has no idea why)

I've made a screen, you can find here [Classic asp outlining issue screen shot 1](http://edeneight.com/_temp/stupidasp.gif)

Has anyone else had this problem? Am I missing something simple?

Thanks for your help
-Birk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution that I've found to work is this.  For classic asp code on a page ending with a .asp extension you can manage outlining of code by placing different functions or pieces in an asp script block `<% %>`.

Then outlining works as expected for those sections. I would still like to find a better option than this however.

Answer (score 4):

You can reset your settings by going to Tools -> Import/Export Settings -> Reset All Settings. I suggest you back up your current settings just in case.

You can also run `devenv /setup` from the command-line and it will reset your Intellisense and such.

Comment: This seems to have helped the Intellisense view partially... I'm still not getting auto case correction for Intellisense completed code.

Comment: Thanks Robert! Just had the same problem in VS2008 C++ and this did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, go to TOOLS -> OPTIONS -> Text Editor -> Basic -> VB Specific

and check "Enable Outlining Mode"

Answer (score 1):

- Tools / Options / Text Editor / File Extension
- extension = asp
- editor = "Web Form Editor"
- click "Add"
- Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I've had the problem in both VS2005 and VS2008 - it comes and goes with no real pattern, and I never found a good solution. Sometimes closing the project and re-starting VS will solve it for a while...but not always.

Comment: I've opened and closed the project multiple times a day for several months now with no change :(

Answer (score 0):

@ Language="VBScript" seems to do the trick for me.  Too bad I have to update all my code to include this now...