# Outlining in VS2008, C++, not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, outlining

I'm using VS2008 (version 9.0.30729.1 SP) and have found that outlining regularly stops working.  I get outlining options for the start and end of functions, and for comment blocks, but not for other code blocks, such as ifs, while loops, for loops, etc...  Using Reset all settings, as recommended in a [similar previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781985/visual-studio-2008-sp1-classic-asp-intellisense-and-outlining-not-functioning.) temporarily fixes the problem, but it comes back going in and out of visual studio.  It also has the side effect of requiring me to reset all my C++ directories.  Any ideas how to resolve this?

**Edit:**  Using Right Click / Outlining / Collapse block works, but is a bit tedious.  I'd really like to see the embedded pluss and minus symbols on the graphic outline. I've tried all the other outlining sub-menu options but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion would be to write a script which every couple of hours adds a randomized post to the VS2008 support forums, requesting that this feature be made more robust, until someone at MS promises to improve it. ;-)

More seriously, you might make a copy of the VS configuration settings files, work until the bug reoccurs, then make another copy, and diff the two versions to see what might have changed. That might give a clue, since resetting the settings seems to fix it temporarily.

Comment: Nah, I like the first suggestion way better ;)